# Nest or unflatten array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects that looks something like this.

```
var arr = [{'id':21 ,'name' : 'name 1' ,'vehiclename' : 'vehicle 1' ,'parentid' : 21},
           {'id':21 ,'name' : 'name 1' ,'vehiclename' : 'vehicle 2' ,'parentid' : 21},
           {'id':22 ,'name' : 'name 2' ,'vehiclename' : 'vehicle 1' ,'parentid' : 22},
           {'id':22 ,'name' : 'name 2' ,'vehiclename' : 'vehicle 2' ,'parentid' : 22}]
```

I would like to unflatten or group the array to now look something like this.

```
var arr = [{'id':21,
             name: 'name 1'
             vehicles : [{'vehiclename':'vehicle 1','parentid':21},
                         {'vehiclename':'vehicle 2','parentid':21}] },
           {'id':22,
             name: 'name 2'
             vehicles : [{'vehiclename':'vehicle 1','parentid':22},
                         {'vehiclename':'vehicle 2','parentid':22}] }
           }]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code so far, what have you tried? What problem did you encounter? Can you post a live demo?

Comment: I think you will have to write a loop which resorts them into a new array

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It seems you are confusing JavaScript object/array literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly. See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Thanks Felix I am very new to these technologies.

Comment: @elclanrs I have not tried anything yet. was hoping for a point in the right direction.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to move the `parentid` out of the nested array in your desired output format? (At least, for the data you show each `parentid` for a given `id` is the same.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those curious, here's an underscore solution:

```
grouped = _.map(_.groupBy(arr, 'id'), function(b) {
    return _.extend(_.pick(b[0], 'id', 'name'), {
        vehicles: _.map(b, function(elem) {
            return _.pick(elem, 'vehiclename', 'parentid')
        })
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bgAzH/1/

Comment: elegent solution using underscore.

Comment: I have a situation now where there a duplicate vehicle being added to the vehicles array , is there any way to check if the vehicle is in the child array.

Comment: @StantonRoux: does that mean that the source array contains two identical elements?

Comment: Yes im trying to fix that issue but , it might happen and would like to check for that

Comment: @StantonRoux: try applying [`uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) to the source before processing it.

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged your question with "underscore.js", and I'm sure underscore would make this easier, but since I'm not familiar with it here's a solution that uses [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
var working = {},
    output = [],
    id,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    id = arr[i].id;
    if (!(id in working))
        working[id] = {id : id, name : arr[i].name, vehicles : []};

    working[id].vehicles.push({vehiclename : arr[i].vehiclename,
                               parentid : arr[i].parentid});
}

for (i in working)
    output.push(working[i]);

// output is now an array of objects in your desired format
```

Rather than directly producing the new `output` array I've started with a `working` object so that it is easy to test whether a given `id` has been seen yet. Then I take each item in the `working` object and put it into an actual array.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it a little more configurable, doesn't look as nice as the given solutions but decides itself if a property should be an array in the final object, also allows to configure keys to be mapped to a certain key in the final object, maybe this is helpful for a more generic case.

```
var _ = require("underscore")

var res = []

var arr = [
  {'id':21 ,'name' : 'name1' ,'vehiclename' : 'vehicle1' ,'parentid' : 21},
  {'id':21 ,'name' : 'name1' ,'vehiclename' : 'vehicle2' ,'parentid' : 21},
  {'id':22 ,'name' : 'name2' ,'vehiclename' : 'vehicle1' ,'parentid' : 22},
  {'id':22 ,'name' : 'name2' ,'vehiclename' : 'vehicle2' ,'parentid' : 22},
]

var connected = [{
  name: "vehicles",
  props: [ "vehiclename", "parentid" ]
}]

arr.forEach(function(e) {
  var obj = _.findWhere(res, { id: e.id })
  if(!obj) {
    obj = { id: e.id }
    res.push(obj)
  }
  var props = _.omit(e, "id");
  connected.forEach(function(cp) {
    props = _.omit.apply(this, [props, cp.props])
  })
  for(p in props) {
    copyPropToObj(props[p], p, obj);
  }
  connected.forEach(function(cp) {
    copyPropToObj(_.pick.apply(this, [e, cp.props]), cp.name, obj)
  })
})

function copyPropToObj(prop, propName, obj) {
  var oProp = _.clone(obj[propName])
  if(oProp && (prop === oProp)) {
    return
  } else if(oProp) {
    // we already have a value, need to move to an array
    obj[propName] = []
    obj[propName].push(prop)
    obj[propName].push(oProp)
  } else {
    // we don't have it set yet so just copy over
    obj[propName] = prop
  }
}

res.forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(e)
})
```